# Why do i get black screen instead of frames in my kivy app

Tags: python, sockets, kivy, kivymd

So i have kivy app that shows real time frames that it got from server side program on pc. While running on pc it works fine but when running on phone it shows black screen instead of frames (only `Image` widget is black screen everything else is fine.
Here is kivy (client side):

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
import socket
import cv2
import pickle
import struct
from datetime import datetime
import threading

class Angelus(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.text= "CONNECT"
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.show_popup(), 0)
        self.image = Image(size_hint = (1, 0.8))
        layout.add_widget(self.image)
        #self.button = MDRaisedButton()
        self.label = MDLabel(text=self.text,
                             adaptive_height = True,
                             halign='center', valign='middle')
        layout.add_widget(self.label)

        self.counter = 0

        self.data = b""
        self.payload_size = struct.calcsize("Q")



        return layout


    def show_popup(self):
        content = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing='12dp', padding='12dp')

        text_field = MDTextField(
            size_hint = (0.84, None)
        )
        content.add_widget(text_field)

        dialog = MDDialog(
            title='Enter your IP',
            md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.bg_dark,
            size_hint=(0.8, None),
            height=200,
            auto_dismiss=False,
            buttons=[
                MDRaisedButton(
                    text="CONNECT",
                    on_release=lambda *args: self.on_ok(dialog, text_field.text)
                ),
            ],
        )

        dialog.add_widget(content)
        dialog.open()


    def on_ok(self, dialog, text):
        # Store the entered text in a variable
        self.host_ip = text
        self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.data_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        #self.host_ip = '192.168.1.8'
        self.port = 1055
        self.port2 = 1077
        self.client_socket.connect((self.host_ip, self.port))
        self.data_socket.connect((self.host_ip, self.port2))
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.update_data(self.data_socket), 1 / 2)
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.update_frame(self.client_socket), 1.0 / 30.0)
        dialog.dismiss()

    def update_frame(self, dt):

        while len(self.data) < self.payload_size:
            packet = self.client_socket.recv(4 * 1024)
            if not packet: break
            self.data += packet
        packet_msg_size = self.data[:self.payload_size]
        self.data = self.data[self.payload_size:]
        msg_size = struct.unpack("Q", packet_msg_size)[0]

        while len(self.data) < msg_size:
            self.data += self.client_socket.recv(4 * 1024)
        frame_data = self.data[:msg_size]
        self.data = self.data[msg_size:]

        frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)

        buffer = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tobytes()
        texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture.blit_buffer(buffer, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        self.image.texture = texture

    def update_data(self, dt):
        data2 = str(self.data_socket.recv(1024).decode())
        self.counter= self.counter +1
        print(data2[0])
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        if (self.counter==1):
            self.label.text = "CONNECTED"
            self.label.size_hint_x = None
            self.label.width = self.label.texture_size[0]
            data2 = []
        elif data2[0] == "5":
            self.label.text = "MOVED AT: " + current_time
            self.label.size_hint_x = None
            self.label.width = self.label.texture_size[0]
            data2 = []


Angelus().run()
```

and here is server side :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import socket
import pickle
import struct
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
from object_detection.utils import config_util
import threading

@tf.function
def detect_fn(image):
    image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(image)
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
    detections = detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
    return detections

def send_frames(image_np_with_detections,client_socket):
    a = pickle.dumps(image_np_with_detections)
    message = struct.pack("Q", len(a)) + a
    client_socket.sendall(message)

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
data_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_name = socket.gethostname()
host_ip = '192.168.1.8'
print('Host IP:', host_ip)
port = 1055
port2= 1077
socket_address = (host_ip, port)
data_address = (host_ip, port2)

server_socket.bind(socket_address)
data_socket.bind(data_address)

TF_RECORD_SCRIPT_NAME = 'generate_tfrecord.py'
LABEL_MAP_NAME = 'label_map.pbtxt'

paths = {
    'CHECKPOINT_PATH': os.path.join('zavrseni modeli', 'model jaje'),
 }

files = {
    'PIPELINE_CONFIG': os.path.join('zavrseni modeli', 'model jaje', 'pipeline.config'),
    'LABELMAP': os.path.join('zavrseni modeli', 'model jaje', 'label_map.pbtxt')
}

configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(files['PIPELINE_CONFIG'])
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=configs['model'], is_training=False)

ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(os.path.join(paths['CHECKPOINT_PATH'], 'ckpt-31')).expect_partial()


category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap (files['LABELMAP'])
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

server_socket.listen(5)
data_socket.listen(5)
print("LISTENING AT: ",socket_address)
print("LISTENING AT: ",data_address)
client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
client_data, addr2 = data_socket.accept()
print('GOT CONNECTION FROM: ', addr)
print('GOT CONNECTION FROM: ', addr2)
ko=0
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image_np = np.array(frame)
    if image_np is not None:

        input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
        detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
        if detections is not None :
            num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
            detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                              for key, value in detections.items()}
            detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

            detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

            label_id_offset = 1
            image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

            viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np_with_detections,
                detections['detection_boxes'],
                detections['detection_classes'] + label_id_offset,
                detections['detection_scores'],
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                max_boxes_to_draw=1,
                min_score_thresh=.7,
                agnostic_mode=False)
            '''
            a = pickle.dumps(image_np_with_detections)
            message = struct.pack("Q", len(a)) + a
            client_socket.sendall(message)
            '''
            client_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_frames, args=(image_np_with_detections, client_socket))
            client_thread.start()
            cv2.imshow("Detections",image_np_with_detections)


            min_score_thresh = .7
            threshold = 0.5
            max_scores = max(detections['detection_scores'])
            for i in range(num_detections):
                box = detections['detection_boxes'][i]
                score = detections['detection_scores'][i]
                if score > .7:
                    ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = box.tolist()
                    pos = ymin + ymax + xmax + xmin
                    print("POS:", pos)
                    print("KO: ",ko)

                    x = abs(pos-ko)
                    print(x)
                    if x>0.05:
                        print("Poslato")
                        client_data.send(str(5).encode())
                        ko = pos
                    else :
                        print("nije poslato")
                        ko = pos
                else :
                    client_data.send(str(0).encode())
        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            client_socket.close()
            client_data.close()
            break
```

I tried adding `thread` module and it shows same black screen. And as you can see i have 2 sockets one for frame and one for data and data socket is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that in these two lines `texture=Texture.create(size(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')`and `texture.blit_buffer(buffer, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')` i had `colorfmt='bgr'` but android standard was `rgb` so when changed it to `colorfmt='rgb'` on both lines it was good.